# Should I request a change of my project in my internship?

Tags: internship, software

I recently had a pre-meet for my internship, where I was assigned a project. The work hasn't started yet and the problem statement given was a little abstract. So I had to research a bit on it and the more I research the more I realize how complex the problem is. The project is heavily based on graph databases, UI/UX which I had never worked with. It is a 2-month internship starting next week. I feel, there is a very high chance I will not be able to deliver what is asked. I have to work alone on this and there is very little documentation available.
Should I request a change in the project or should I try the project anyways?

I am very confused, please help!

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, speak up. Share your concerns now!

Also, a good internship is supposed to provide structure and mentorship. If they're not planning to give you that kind of support, that's a problem as well.

Do you have a CS Professor who knows you that you can speak to? A professor who knows your capabilities should be able to tell if this internship is a good idea for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

It might seem complex cause you're trying to understand everything NOW. Two months is enough to gradually learn something, that's what internships are for. In my opinion, building a UI for a graph database (if that's what you're going to do) is pretty interesting.

Maybe instead of requesting a change, ask first if it's okay to learn about things during the project because you know nothing about it, and if it's okay if you don't deliver as requested. And most importantly, ask if you're going to be mentored.

Then, if they say no, ask them to change it. If you don't like the project at all and you don't even want to learn about it, just tell them to give you something else.

It's important to tell them now before you get stuck in a project that is too complex or too boring for you. Most people lose motivation and deliver the bare minimum (sometimes even less) when they face a project too complex to deal with in such a short time.